# require JS reloading the whole page on changing modules.

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, requirejs, marionette

I am working on a web app using Backbone, Marionette and requirejs. The app contains marionette modules which are taking care of different routes. The dependencies of the modules are loaded by require.js. The app contains one nav-bar and rest of the page is the Page description. The links in the nav-bar are handled by different modules.

The main problem is when I switch between modules then The index.html reloads and loads all the dependencies of config.js. But I just want to reload only the page body not the nav bar. I am new to this stack so please help me out.

> index.html
>
> ```
>   <!-- REQUIRE JS Configuration -->       
>
>   <script data-main="/modules/config.js" >src="/static/lib/requirejs/require.js" async></script>
>
>   <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?>family=Oswald:400,300,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
> ```

requirejs's config.js

```
require.config({
waitSeconds: 10,
paths: {
    templates: "./../templates",
    jquery: "/static/lib/jquery/jquery.min",
    jquerymigrate: "/static/lib/jquery/jquery-migrate.min",
    jqueryui: "/static/lib/jqueryui/ui/minified/jquery-ui.custom.min",
    bootstrap: "/static/lib/bootstrap-3.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap",
    moment: "/static/lib/moment/min/moment.min",
},

shim: {
    'jquerymigrate': ['jquery'],
    'jquerybackstretch': ['jquery'],
    'jqueryuniform': ['jquery'],
    'jqueryui': ['jquery','jquerymigrate'],
    'bootstrap': ['jquery'],
    'fancybox': ['jquery']
},})
```

Comment: *" when I switch between modules then The index.html reloads"* - I doubt that. how are you triggering this switch? What do you mean page body? Is that a marionette view? Can you create a [mcve] demonstrating the issue?

Comment: Thanks @TJ for your help, And yes the body view is a marionette view. Here is the fiddle. Please check it. https://jsfiddle.net/Soumen_Naskar/mh1nfg8w/